# CAT6: Assembling cable: RJ45 connectors

Tags: rj45, cable-assemblies

What do I need to check for when assembling RJ45 cables. I had some left over CAT6 cable from when I wired my home, and I bought some CAT6 RJ45 connectors from a local store:

[image]

I cannot even push the individual color cable through the plastic guide:

[image]

So there is definitely something that is not compatible, or at least CAT6 is not enough to combine them. What should I look for on my cable spec to know for sure:

[image]

[image]

Which leads to:

- [NEX C6 450 F/UTP LSZH Dca 4P 500m IVOIRE](https://www.nexans.fr/eservice/France-fr_FR/navigateproduct_540339040/NEX_C6_450_F_UTP_LSZH_Dca_4P_500m_IVOIRE.html#characteristics)

Comment: You've got 24awg wire but you're trying to use connectors designed for 26awg wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the spec, it seems that the diameter is not compatible with what I bought:

> Diamètre sur isolation    1,13mm

while typical dexlan 920880 are designed for CAT.6, STP, AWG 24-26 but:

> DIAMÈTRE MAX FILS 1,05 mm

---

Update: I was able to plug the rj45 connectors to my cable using dexlan 920818 connectors:

[image]

One can visually see they are much different from the other ones:

[image]